# Can't get Mongoose virtuals to be part of the result object

Tags: virtual, mongoose

bI'm declaring a virtual that I want to appear as part of the results of its schema's queries, but it's not showing up when I do a console.log on the object. Here's the schema:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    Name: { type: String }
},
{
    toObject: { virtuals: true }
});

schema.virtual("Greet").get(function()
{
    return "My name is " + this.Name;
});
```

Should that toObject not set the virtual as a property of the results of any queries? It does not, nor does schema.set("toObject", { virtuals: true }). Am I doing this right?

Comment: I'm using version 3.3.1.

Comment: myModel.find({}).exec(function(err, results)
{
   console.log(JSON.stringify(results[0]));
}

Comment: @MikePateras - did you end up getting this working? If so, how? I'm having exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 73):

Because you're using `JSON.stringify` in your `console.log` call, that invokes the `toJSON` method on the model instance, not `toObject`.

So either omit the `JSON.stringify` in your call:

```js
console.log(results[0]);
```

Or set the [`toJSON`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toJSON) option on the schema like you're currently setting the `toObject` option.

```js
{
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
});
```

Comment: I have had this same problem for at least 2 days - and no combination of toObject/toJSON with virtuals enabled has worked. I just can't get virtuals to output. Driving me absolutely batty!

Comment: I ended up fixing it - I wasn't aware I needed both of these properties to be defined. Drove me nuts. lol

Comment: Great question; great answer. This should be accepted as correct.

Comment: Defining both properties for `toObject` and `toJSON` worked for me

Comment: Where does the documentation state that you have to add  toObject: { virtuals: true }, toJSON: { virtuals: true } ?

Comment: @ChrisRch that's the whole point [there is nothing about it](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/virtuals.html)

Comment: That's one of the biggest downsides of Mongoose. Poor documentation and quirks. Currently working on a project using native MongoDB driver without Mongoose. A bit more cumbersome but gets the job done.

Comment: In Mongoose v4.0 I am able to get virtuals to work after a query with only `toJSON: { virtuals: true }`, no need for `toObject: { virtuals: true }`

Comment: This worked for me. 
UserSchema.set('toJSON', { getters: true, virtuals: true });
UserSchema.set('toObject', { getters: true, virtuals: true });

Comment: @ChrisRich: You can trace back to 2.7.X docs the `virtuals` option in `toObject` and `toJSON`. [Here's](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) the current one.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I dont understand why mongoose invokes  toJSON  automatically ?

Comment: @Suhayb Mongoose doesn't invoke it, `JSON.stringify()` does. From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify): "If the value has a toJSON() method, it's responsible to define what data will be serialized."

Answer (score 2):

My mistake was not including the needed fields in the query.
If they are not selected in projection, then mongoose does not knows how to combine/calculate the virtual field.

Comment: I had the problem with a redefined _id field (random string), and _id fields are always projected.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up here doing something really silly. I was using `Doc.find` instead of `Doc.findOne` and so I was trying to access the virtual on the document array instead of on the document itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
userSchema.virtual('fullName').get(function () {
   return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName
});
```

```
const doc = await model.findOne(query);
return doc.toObject({ virtuals: true });
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?