# Populate a mongoose model with a field that isn't an id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to populate a mongoose model with a field of a reference model that isn't the _id ... e.g. a username.

so something like

```
var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  age     : Number,
  stories : { type: String, field: "username", ref: 'Story' }
});
```

Comment: Fast forward to 2017, and Frosty's answer should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

You may use the `populate()` API. 
The API is more flexible, you don't have to specify `ref` and `field` in the Schema.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate

You can mix and match with `find()`.

Comment: I can't understand from the docs. Could you give an example query?

Comment: Coming to SO only after reading the documentation, if I understood it I wouldn't search for answers here.

Comment: You still need to configure your Schema for populate to be use, by adding reference.

Answer (score 102):

This is supported since **Mongoose 4.5**, and is called **[virtuals population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)**.

You have to define your **foreign keys relationships** after your **schemas definitions** and before **creating models**, like this:

```
// Schema definitions

BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        ...,
        title: String,
        authorId: Number,
        ...
    },
    // schema options: Don't forget this option
    // if you declare foreign keys for this schema afterwards.
    {
        toObject: {virtuals:true},
        // use if your results might be retrieved as JSON
        // see http://stackoverflow.com/q/13133911/488666
        //toJSON: {virtuals:true} 
    });

PersonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({id: Number, ...});


// Foreign keys definitions

BookSchema.virtual('author', {
  ref: 'Person',
  localField: 'authorId',
  foreignField: 'id',
  justOne: true // for many-to-1 relationships
});


// Models creation

var Book = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);


// Querying

Book.find({...})
    // if you use select() be sure to include the foreign key field !
    .select({.... authorId ....}) 
    // use the 'virtual population' name
    .populate('author')
    .exec(function(err, books) {...})
```

Comment: I just assume it as the answer

Comment: It is returning all properties of `author`, how do I specify the `.populate('author')` to only return specific fields?

Comment: Ah, found the answer in the docs, https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#field-selection. Anyway thanks for the asnwer.

Comment: It this work in nestjs/mongoose also?

Comment: Yes, but the syntax is different.
Everything is explained in this doc page https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb (search for keyword "relation").

Answer (score 3):

It seems they enforce to use `_id`, and maybe we can customize it in the future.

Here is the issue on Github https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/2562

Comment: This github issue was closed in favor of using the new [virtuals population](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of using the $lookup aggregate to populate a model called Invite with the respective User based on the corresponding `email` field:

```
  Invite.aggregate(
      { $match: {interview: req.params.interview}},
      { $lookup: {from: 'users', localField: 'email', foreignField: 'email', as: 'user'} }
    ).exec( function (err, invites) {
      if (err) {
        next(err);
      }

      res.json(invites);
    }
  );
```

It's probably quite similar to what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Frosty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39869551/12754665), if you're looking to **refer to an array of documents of another collection** you would make changes like so.

```
BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    title: String,
    authorId: [Number],
},
// schema options: Don't forget this option
// if you declare foreign keys for this schema afterwards.
{
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    // use if your results might be retrieved as JSON
    // see http://stackoverflow.com/q/13133911/488666
    toJSON: {virtuals:true}
});

PersonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ id: Number, name: String });

BookSchema.virtual("author", {
ref: "Person",
localField: ["authorId"],
foreignField: ["id"],
// justOne: true, // Needs to be commented out in this scenario, 
});
```