# relations in mongoose with custom field

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I've seen many examples about mongoose and relations, but how can I create a reference to another entity into a custom field ?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
mongoose.connection.once('open', function(){

  var Author = m.model('Author', new m.Schema({
    name: String,
    slugname: String
  }));
  var Book = m.model('Book', new m.Schema({
    title: String,
    author: {type: String, ref: 'Author.slugname'}
  }));

});
```

In the code above, I'm linking Book.author into Author.slugname. it is just that I don't if this is the right way to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate a mongoose model with a field that isn't an id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287142/populate-a-mongoose-model-with-a-field-that-isnt-an-id)

Answer (score 6):

This is supported since **Mongoose 4.5**, and is called **[virtuals population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)**.

Check [**my detailed answer on this (nearly duplicate) question**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39869551/488666).

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't. Mongoose always use `_id` field to link documents. But...

You can set your own `_id` for each document, using any datatype you want. There are only two restrictions:

- it should be unique
- it should not be changed during document's lifetime

So, instead of adding new `slugname` field, use author's `_id` as a slugname:

```
var Author = m.model('Author', new m.Schema({
  _id: String, // <-- slugname
  name: String
}));
var Book = m.model('Book', new m.Schema({
  title: String,
  author: { type: String, ref: 'Author' }
}));
```

Comment: Is this a good practice ?

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose is set up more for direct object relations. Rather than linking your `Book` object to a slug for the `Author` object, it would suit better to link to the Author's `_id` property automatically created by Mongoose.

```
var Author = mongoose.model('Author', new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});
var Book = mongoose.model('Book', new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String
    author: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Author' }
});
```

You can then save an `Author` as the `author` of the `Book` object by either saving `book.author = author` or `book.author = author._id`. Mongoose will automatically serialize the data when saving.

```
var author = new Author();
author.name = 'Hank Brekke';

var book = new Book();
book.title = 'My Book';
book.author = author;

book.save();
```

When pulling the book object, you can have Mongoose automatically populate the `author` property, which by default it will not, by adding the `.populate('author')` modifier before calling `.exec()`

```
Book.findOne({ /* query */}).populate('author').exec(function(error, book) {
    var author = book.author;
});
```

#### References:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html