# Nodejs Mongoose : ref on another propertiy

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I`m trying create ref from one collection to another collection but not with ref on id.

For example: I have two schema, user and foo. Foo has one unique property 'name'.

**USER**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    foo: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Foo'
    }
});
mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

**FOO**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const fooSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
        index: {
            unique: true
        }
    }
});
mongoose.model('Foo', fooSchema);
```

This is work perfect, but can I do ref on that unique property (not on _id)? Like this:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    foo: {
        type: String,
        property: 'name',
        ref: 'Foo'
    }
});
```

Thanks for any answers ;)

Comment: read this for some insights https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468443/relations-in-mongoose-with-custom-field