# Mongoose object id constraint

Tags: node.js, database, mongoose, size, objectid

hello I'm working with mongoose and after a long time I still dont know how to fix this error... I tried during several hours to fix it but every time I just 'hide' the problem by complete the field with random character but for my project I cant, I need a precise Id so if someone could help with an example if he can, it will be really nice

> Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a
>   string of 24 hex characters

I m trying to create an Id like : map1AssigneSeat

And to persist I use this code where mapId is equal to  map1AssigneSeat:

```
var rowData = new MapDatabase({ 
  MapDescription:  mongoose.Types.ObjectId(mapId),
  DeckNumber: Number(map.Deck[i].DeckNumber),
  x: Number(map.Deck[i].x),
  y: Number(map.Deck[i].y),
});
```

Comment: Just leave Mongo id as is. If you need custom identifier, you could add `mapId` field.

Comment: but to join two table I need an objectId no ?

Comment: You need id, not necessarily ObjectId. If you believe this is needed, you can replace id types. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468443/relations-in-mongoose-with-custom-field

Comment: ok but basically when I will try to join the index will be only on _id ? Because I need two Id for a collection in my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mongoose.Types.ObjectId` always expect 24 characters that is a hexadecimal character like `5b6159a1034cf06b23aa2382` which is equivalent to 12 bytes. The error is due to incorrect length of 24 digits hexadecimal character. Check the value and length of `mapId` which you are passing in as a parameter. It must satisfy 24 digits hexadecimal characters to resolve that error.

You can however add some fixed characters like say you have 20 characters of `mapId` then add 4 characters of hexadecimals like `abcd` to make it total of 24 and use that.

Comment: And there is no any way to override this constraint ?

Comment: @Chris unfortunately no. Because that is the inbuilt function of the library

Comment: @Chris you can however add some fixed characters like say you have 20 characters of `mapId` then add 4 characters of hexadecimals like `abcd` to make it total of `24` and use that

Comment: @Chris I have updated the answer. You can tick mark it so that it will be useful for future visitors