# Mongoose _id to unit64

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I need a `unit64` ID in my MongoDB database. ObjectIds are 96 bits.
I have seen the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672423/mongoose-object-id-constraint) that one way to do it is to add a few constant characters to the beginning of the ID. But how d I achieve this in Mongoose?

Suppose that I have a schema like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
 _id: {
      ???
 },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `nanoid` for now:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const { customAlphabet } = require('nanoid');
const alphabet = '123456789';
const nanoid = customAlphabet(alphabet, 19); //from 11...111 to 99...999

const mySchema = new Schema({
  int_id: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    default: () => nanoid()
  },
});
```