# Concat two document properties in query options mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm sorry if this is extremely simple mongodb has documentation on aggregate $concat however I might be misunderstanding its purpose. I am trying to combine my first and last name properties like so.

LastName, FirstName

I will also add middle initial at the end but I don't want to complicate things.

```
var query = model.find(); //for simplicity I'm selecting all of them
query.aggregate({name:{$concat:['$LastName', ', ', '$FirstName']}})
query.exec(function(err, docs){
    if(err) throw err; //trying to understand why this isn't working
})
```

This causes the route that fetches this information to return status 500 however no error is thrown. Am I going about this the wrong way. The actual
code limits the output to 1000 because there are over 200,000 entries in the database and it seems kinda silly to loop through them all and combine them if mongoose can do some of the work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I was using aggregate wrong. I instead found that I can use virtuals to do the same thing.

by modifying my schema

```
var s = new Schema({//someschema},{
    toObject:true,
    toJSON:true
});
s.virtual('FullName').get(function(){
    return this.LastName + ', ' + this.FirstName;
});
```

then I after I make a query without the aggregate I can call 
doc.FullName //Last, First

thank you goes to @JohnnyHK and his answer on [Can't get Mongoose virtuals to be part of the result object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133911/cant-get-mongoose-virtuals-to-be-part-of-the-result-object)